# How can I show that the following two polar equations are the same, without graphing them? $r=8-\sin(2x)$ and $r=\sin(2x)-8$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How can I show in what sense the following two polar equations are “the same”:
$$r=8-\sin (2x)$$ and $$r=\sin (2x)-8$$
They trace out the same graph.
They are polar equations - consider the x to be a theta.

Comment: Do you notice a relationship between the two equations, just by looking at them?

Comment: they are not equal as signs are opposite

Comment: By $x$ you mean polar angle $\theta?$  It rotates the first graph by $\pi$. Or is symmetrical  about line $ x+y=0$

Comment: It could help to explain the notation here. I can somehow see what this intends to ask, but it would be much simpler if the relation between $r$ and $x$ would be explained and the domain specified. Also what does it mean for equations to be the same, that they have the same set of solutions, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you're obviously allowing negative $r$.

Now, the transformation $$z\mapsto -z$$can be expressed in two ways, the first way, (1), is

$$r\mapsto -r$$

or, another way, (2):

$$\theta \mapsto \theta + (2n+1)\pi$$

Let's start with your first equation,

$$r=8-\sin 2x$$

Perform (1) to get

$$r=\sin 2x - 8$$

Then perform (2). Note that $\sin 2\theta$ is $\pi$- periodic, so the equation is unchanged.

Overall we have composed $z\mapsto -z$ with itself. So, we have done nothing at all (identity map overall).

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same because $r>0$.
In the first case $r=8-\sin 2x >0$ but in the second case$ r=\sin 2x-8<0$. Hence the second equation  represents a null set: no curve in $(r,\theta)$ space.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinate equations are usually defined only for $r\ge0$. But, as a matter of fact, graphing softwares (such as Desmos or GeoGebra) and even some books (see for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3749864/255730) about an exercise in Spivak's Calculus book) allow for negative values of $r$.

To give a meaning to negative values of $r$, they make the most natural choice: they assume that $(,\ )$ corresponds, when $<0$, to the point $(−,\ +180°)$ (i.e. a negative radius means that the point lies in the opposite direction with respect to $θ$).

I don't know if this extension of polar coordinates to $<0$ is widely accepted, but it is enforced in graphing softwares because to graph a polar equation like $r=(\theta)$ they transform it into the parametric curve
$$
x=f(\theta)\cos⁡\theta \quad y=f(\theta)\sin⁡\theta 
$$
and a negative value of $(\theta)$ amounts at taking the opposite vector, as described above.

In the case of $=\sin2\theta-8$, for example, we can then define $′=−$ and
$′=+180°$, which inserted into the equation give: $-r'=\sin(2\theta'-360°)-8$,
that is: $r'=-\sin2\theta'+8$, which is the "right" equation.
Hence a graphing software will show in both cases the same graph.

Comment: Thank you very much Aretino.  Yes, Jame Stewart Calculus book defines negative r this way.  A TI-84 traces out the same graph for both equations but in the second case starts at pi and traces the curve out in the opposite direction.  I was looking for the analytical explanation of it - thanks.